# self [action] () - это список или что это?

Tags: javascript, list, prototype, делегаты

И если это список, то почему он создаётся как переменная?

И как это работает тогда?

```js
function Menu(elem) {
  this.save = function() {
    alert('сохраняю');
  };
  this.load = function() {
    alert('загружаю');
  };
  this.search = function() {
    alert('ищу');
  };

  var self = this;

  elem.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var action = target.getAttribute('data-action');
    if (action) {
      self[action]();
    }
  };
}

new Menu(menu);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
  <button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
  <button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, к св-ву/методу объекта можно обратиться двумя способами

1 - через точку ( дот нотация )

```
const a = {
  method: (str) => alert(str),
  prop: 'prop'
}
a.method(a.prop);
```

2 - через скобки квадратные

```
const a = {
  method: (str) => alert(str),
  prop: 'prop'
}
a['method'](a['prop']);
```

Раз во втором варианте используется строчка, то мы эту строку можем сохранить в переменную

```
const a = {
  method: (str) => alert(str),
  prop: 'prop'
}
const action = 'method';
a[action](a['prop']); // передали именно переменную, которая вернула нужный метод/св-во
```

В вашем коде как раз это и происходит, `getAttribute` возвращает значение атрибута в виде строки, которую мы дальше используем, что бы вызвать нужный метод объекта

Comment: А в моём случае,self  это переменная в которую мы сохраняем атрибуты в виде строки,но это же не объект

Comment: всё я разобрался, спасибо!